How to serve unique error pages for each subdirectory using Nginx?
I have a directory where are many Jekyll sites with their own themes, etc. I want to serve unique error pages for each Jekyll site. In each directory there are such files:
# ls /var/www/pages/
site1 site2 site3

# ls /var/www/pages/site1
... 404.html  50x.html ...

Currently I have the following Nginx config (/etc/nginx/sites-{available,enabled}/pages, which doesn't work:
server {

        server_name REDACTED;

        root /var/www/pages;
        # index index.html;

        location / {
                autoindex on;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~* ^(/[^/]+) {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                error_page 404 /404.html;
                error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        }
}

